# new Object with prototype function vs regular function which returns an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

The basic idea is to check if it starts with an underscore and if there is split the string and return whatever comes after the underscore. This function will be run many times, but for different strings, it is unlikely i will need to retrieve the information more than once for each stirng.

A simple function which will return an object with the data I need:

```
var parseElementName = function(i) {
    var sliced  = [i.slice(0, 1), i.slice(1, i.length)];
    var obj     = {
        isClass: null,
        name: ''
    }

    if(sliced[0] === '_') {
        obj.name = sliced[1];
        obj.isClass = true;
    } else {
        obj.name = i;
        obj.isClass = false;
    }

    return obj
}
```

Called with `parseElementName(i);`

Object with prototyped function

```
var parsedElement = function(i) {
    this.className = 
    this.isClass = null;

    if(this.setElementName(i))
        return true
}

parsedElement.prototype.setElementName = function(i) {
    var sliced = [i.slice(0, 1), i.slice(1, i.length)];

    if(sliced[0] === '_') {
        this.className = sliced[1];
        this.isClass = true
    } else {
        this.className = i;
        this.isClass = false
    }
}
```

Called with `var parsed_element = new parsedElement();`
then `parsed_element.className` or `parsedElement.isClass`

Which approach is recommended?

Comment: Why do you have an if statement in your constructor that will never return true? You may as well just do `this.setElementName(i)` instead of `if(this.setElementName(i))` because setElementName doesn't return anything so the if statement will never be true.

Comment: yeah sorry posted this midway through modifying the code, previously it was returning something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the object prototype approach best, but I have a few notes about your code:

1. Use semicolons at the end of each line
2. Class names should be capitalized. So it should be `ParsedElement`
3. I wouldn't call it `className`, because it is confusing when it is not a class, I would rename it `name`

Answer (score 0):

The two ways have different outcomes - that constructor+prototype approach will yield an instance which has a `setElementName` method. Will you ever need this to change the fields of an existing object? It's a simple parser function, so I would assume no. In that case, you should go with returning the object literal:

```
function parseElementName(i) {
    var isClass = i.charAt(0) == '_';
    return {
        isClass: isClass,
        name = isClass ? i.slice(1) : i
    };
}
```

If you really need that method later, consider @MaxMeier's and @HMR's points.